# for loop/function to create new variable by conditional checking of multiple character strings

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement

I am not a new R user but have never had to write loops and I would like to learn as in this case I think it will save time and makes more sense.

I have a large data set that has data on visit frequency to different forest types, a simplified subset of which looks like this:

```
f_type_1 <- sample(c("daily", "weekly", "monthly", "annually", "never"), 10, replace = T)
f_type_2 <- sample(c("daily", "weekly", "monthly", "annually", "never"), 10, replace = T)
f_type_3 <- sample(c("daily", "weekly", "monthly", "annually", "never"), 10, replace = T)
f_type_4 <- sample(c("daily", "weekly", "monthly", "annually", "never"), 10, replace = T)
f_type_5 <- sample(c("daily", "weekly", "monthly", "annually", "never"), 10, replace = T)
forvis<-data.frame(f_type_1, f_type_2, f_type_3, f_type_4, f_type_5)
```

I am not interested in each individual forest type rather I want to create a new variable `forvis$f_vis_freqency` that gives a general forest visit frequency. i.e. I want to write a loop or a function that iterates across the row and populates the new variable with the highest frequency (in this case it would be `"daily"`) based on a conditional `if` statements.eg. `if` the row contains `"daily"` then use `"daily"` `else if` row contains `"weekly"` then use `"weekly"` and so on with monthly, annually and never (in the real data set i have quite a few more to deal with than this)

I have already done this with a large (73 lines of code in the real data) nested `ifelse` call but I fell like there must be a better way to do it.
The current method I am using looks like this:

```
    forvis$f_visit_freqency<-ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="daily" | forvis$f_type_2=="daily" | forvis$f_type_3 =="daily" | forvis$f_type_4 == "daily" | forvis$f_type_5 == "daily", "daily",
                                 ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="weekly" | forvis$f_type_2=="weekly" | forvis$f_type_3 =="weekly" | forvis$f_type_4 == "weekly" | forvis$f_type_5 == "weekly", "weekly",
                                        ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="monthly" | forvis$f_type_2=="monthly" | forvis$f_type_3 =="monthly" | forvis$f_type_4 == "monthly" | forvis$f_type_5 == "monthly", "monthly",
                                               ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="annually" | forvis$f_type_2=="annually" | forvis$f_type_3 =="annually" | forvis$f_type_4 == "annually" | forvis$f_type_5 == "annually", "annually",
                                                      ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="never" | forvis$f_type_2=="never" | forvis$f_type_3 =="never" | forvis$f_type_4 == "never" | forvis$f_type_5 == "never", "never",
                                                             NA))))

                                 )
```

Comment: What is your expected output for given dataframe?

Comment: If two of them have the highest frequency, what will happen?

Comment: @RonakShah and @user2100721, the expected output would look the same as an `f_type_` variable. If the the person from the survey visited all the forest types `"daily"` then the output should be `"daily"`. Similarly, as and example if the respondent visited forest types 1-3 annually type 4 weekly and type 5 never then the output should be weekly. Hope this helps

Comment: It is still not clear to me. You can show output of your expected `forvis$f_vis_freqency`. Do you need something like `apply(forvis, 1, function(x) names(which.max(table(x))))`

Comment: @JoshVanVianen Please see my answer. I can think of four different approaches to achieve this task. I didn't do any analysis on the speed or efficiency of these solutions, but I like solution 3 the most.

Comment: @JoshVanVianen I updated a new solution called solution 5. This the fastest solution by far and much more concise than your original solution. I  recommend this solution.

Comment: @ycw. thanks for all the solutions however I think i have not really made my self clear as to what I'm looking for. When I run my nested `ifelse` I get the correct output. when I run solution 5 I get lots of NAs and some incorrect values

Comment: All the solutions work for your example dataset on my computer. When you said it is not working, are you talking about your example dataset or the real dataset? If there are some key differences between your example dataset and real dataset that cause the solutions not work, you need to figure out what are the key differences are.

Comment: @ycw I have run both my original solution and the F5 solution you posted. see the resultant data frame for differences in the outputs.

Comment: @JoshVanVianen The updated example you provided is different as your original example. You have typos in your updated example. `annualy` should be `annually`. The solution 5 actually works if you correct the typos.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1: Use functions from dplyr and tidyr

It is natural to me to convert such data frame from wide format to long format, and then process the data. `dplyr` and `tidyr` work well on this.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Process the data    
forvis2 <- forvis %>%
  # Create an ID for each person
  mutate(Person = row_number()) %>%
  # Reshape the data frame to long format
  gather(Forest, Frequency, -Person) %>%
  # Convert the Frequency column to factor
  mutate(Frequency = factor(Frequency,
                            levels = c("daily", "weekly", "monthly",
                                       "annually", "never"))) %>%
  # Arrange the data by Person, then by Frequency
  arrange(Person, Frequency) %>%
  # Group by person
  group_by(Person) %>%
  # Only keep the first row for each person
  slice(1)

# Add the frequency to forvis
forvis$f_vis_freqency <- forvis2$Frequency
```

#### Solution 2: Use functions from base R

```
# Transpose the data frame
forvis2 <- as.data.frame(t(forvis))

# Covert each column to the right factor level, save as a list
forvis_list <- lapply(forvis2, 
                      factor, 
                      levels = c("daily", "weekly", "monthly", "annually", "never"))

# Sort each column and select the first one
# Store the result to f_vis_freqency as a new column to forvis
forvis$f_vis_freqency <- sapply(lapply(forvis_list, sort), `[`, 1)
```

#### Solution 3: Use supply to sort each row

The key of this solution is we can use `unlist` to convert the row of a data frame to a vector. If vector is defined, we can then `sort` the vector.

```
# Convert all columns in forvis to the right factor level
forvis2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(forvis, factor, 
                                levels = c("daily", "weekly", "monthly",
                                "annually", "never")))

# Use sapply to apply a function
forvis$f_vis_freqency <- sapply(1:nrow(forvis2),
                            function(i) {sort(unlist(forvis2[i, ]))[1]})
```

#### Solution 4: Define a function then use sapply through each row

We can define a function to return the answer of one row, then use `sapply` to apply this function to each row. Here I demonstrate two such functions.

*** A: A function using multiple ifelse statements***

Notice that this function does not require the users to convert the columns to `factor`. It can work on `character`.

```
# A function to report the frequency label
# i is the row index, while dt is the input data frame
report_freq <- function(i, dt = forvis){

  temp <- unique(unlist(dt[i, ]))

  # Use multiple ifelse statement to test if there are any matching labels
  answer <- ifelse(any(temp %in% "daily"), "daily",
                   ifelse(any(temp %in% "weekly"), "weekly",
                          ifelse(any(temp %in% "monthly"), "monthly",
                                 ifelse(any(temp %in% "annually"), "annually", "never"))))
  return(answer)
}

# Use sapply to apply the function
forvis$f_vis_freqency <- sapply(1:nrow(forvis), report_freq, dt = forvis)
```

*** B: A function using factor level and sort***

This approach does not need to convert every elements of the data frame to `factor`. It reads in the data from each row and returns the answer.

```
# A function to report the frequency label
# i is the row index, while dt is the input data frame
report_freq <- function(i, dt = forvis){

  temp <- unique(unlist(dt[i, ]))

  temp <- factor(temp, levels = c(levels = c("daily", "weekly", "monthly",
                                             "annually", "never")))
  answer <- sort(temp)[1]

  return(answer)
}

# Use sapply to apply the function
forvis$f_vis_freqency <- sapply(1:nrow(forvis), report_freq, dt = forvis)
```

#### Solution 5: Convert factor to numeric then find the minimum

```
# Create the factor level as a vector
factor_level <- c("daily", "weekly", "monthly", "annually", "never")

# Find the index  
ind <- apply(as.data.frame(lapply(forvis, function(x) {
x <- as.numeric(factor(x, levels = factor_level))})), 1, min)

# Return the index with associated character  
forvis$f_vis_freqency <- factor_level[ind]
```

#### Performance Measure

I used the `microbenchmark` library to measure the performance. Here is the result.

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr       min        lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
   S0   582.465   637.633   732.5772   654.953   675.4800  79961.281  5000
   S1 14394.199 15048.831 16353.5785 15363.477 16724.0580 100905.644  5000
   S2  1594.723  1667.852  1841.7731  1710.831  1800.6380   7175.609  5000
   S3  3208.689  3319.986  3681.2132  3394.399  3619.2380  59523.688  5000
  S4a  2041.194  2171.415  2438.0034  2232.034  2367.0660  59986.837  5000
  S4b  3327.363  3457.585  3832.7902  3547.712  3774.1555  58306.156  5000
   S5   554.882   624.803   686.8600   645.972   672.9145   5789.369  5000
```

To my surprise, Solution 0 (OP's original solution) is pretty fast, while solution 5 is the fastest.

Here is the code.

```
library(microbenchmark)

# Solution 0
F0 <- function(){
  ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="daily" | forvis$f_type_2=="daily" | forvis$f_type_3 =="daily" | forvis$f_type_4 == "daily" | forvis$f_type_5 == "daily", "daily",
         ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="weekly" | forvis$f_type_2=="weekly" | forvis$f_type_3 =="weekly" | forvis$f_type_4 == "weekly" | forvis$f_type_5 == "weekly", "weekly",
                ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="monthly" | forvis$f_type_2=="monthly" | forvis$f_type_3 =="monthly" | forvis$f_type_4 == "monthly" | forvis$f_type_5 == "monthly", "monthly",
                       ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="annually" | forvis$f_type_2=="annually" | forvis$f_type_3 =="annually" | forvis$f_type_4 == "annually" | forvis$f_type_5 == "annually", "annually",
                              ifelse(forvis$f_type_1=="never" | forvis$f_type_2=="never" | forvis$f_type_3 =="never" | forvis$f_type_4 == "never" | forvis$f_type_5 == "never", "never",
                                     NA))))

  )
}

# Solution 1
F1 <- function(){
  forvis2 <- forvis %>%
    mutate(Person = row_number()) %>%
    gather(Forest, Frequency, -Person) %>%
    mutate(Frequency = factor(Frequency,
                              levels = c("daily", "weekly", "monthly",
                                         "annually", "never"))) %>%
    arrange(Person, Frequency) %>%
    group_by(Person) %>%
    slice(1)

  forvis2$Frequency
}

# Solution 2
F2 <- function(){
  forvis2 <- as.data.frame(t(forvis))
  forvis_list <- lapply(forvis2, 
                        factor, 
                        levels = c("daily", "weekly", "monthly", "annually", "never"))
  sapply(lapply(forvis_list, sort), `[`, 1)
}

# Solution 3
F3 <- function(){
  forvis2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(forvis, factor, 
                                  levels = c("daily", "weekly", "monthly",
                                             "annually", "never")))
  sapply(1:nrow(forvis2), function(i) {sort(unlist(forvis2[i, ]))[1]})
}

# Solution 4a
F4a <- function(){
  report_freq <- function(i, dt = forvis){

    temp <- unique(unlist(dt[i, ]))
    answer <- ifelse(any(temp %in% "daily"), "daily",
                     ifelse(any(temp %in% "weekly"), "weekly",
                            ifelse(any(temp %in% "monthly"), "monthly",
                                   ifelse(any(temp %in% "annually"), "annually", "never"))))
    return(answer)
  }
  sapply(1:nrow(forvis), report_freq, dt = forvis)
}

# Solution 4b
F4b <- function(){
  report_freq <- function(i, dt = forvis){

    temp <- unique(unlist(dt[i, ]))
    temp <- factor(temp, levels = c(levels = c("daily", "weekly", "monthly",
                                               "annually", "never")))
    answer <- sort(temp)[1]
    return(answer)
  }
  sapply(1:nrow(forvis), report_freq, dt = forvis)
}

# Solution 5
F5 <- function(){
  factor_level <- c("daily", "weekly", "monthly", "annually", "never")
  ind <- apply(as.data.frame(lapply(forvis, function(x) {
    x <- as.numeric(factor(x, levels = factor_level))})), 1, min)
  factor_level[ind]
}

# Measure the performance
microbenchmark(
  S0 = F0(),
  S1 = F1(),
  S2 = F2(),
  S3 = F3(),
  S4a = F4a(),
  S4b = F4b(),
  S5 = F5(),
  times = 5000
)
```